# SharePoint 2013 Office web apps preview not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-web-apps, certificate

I am having issues with the preview of our sharepoint office documents, it is not working, i have checked the OWA Server and the owa services are running . I also checked the binding using Get-SPWOPIBinding and it returned the bindings to the owa server. I have also set the zone to external-https using

```
Set-SPWOPIZone –zone “external-https”
```

because i saw that the zone was binded to external-https in my sharepoint servers. but still the issue is still there.not sure why and I don't understand the ULS logs either. these are the ULS logs for the correlation id of one of the documents i was trying to preview.

> Unexpected Exception in
>   SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory for usage
>   'DistributedLogonTokenCache' - Exception 'System.ArgumentException:
>   Max connections value should be in the range 1 to 100. Parameter name:
>   value at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactoryConfiguration.set_MaxConnectionsToServer(Int32
>   value) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper.InitializeDataCacheFactory()'.
>
> Token Cache: Failed to initialize SPDistributedSecurityTokenCache
>   Exception: 'System.ArgumentException: Max connections value should be
>   in the range 1 to 100. Parameter name: value at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactoryConfiguration.set_MaxConnectionsToServer(Int32
>   value) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper.InitializeDataCacheFactory()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCache..ctor(String
>   name, TimeSpan timeToLive, SPDistributedCacheContainerType
>   containerType, Boolean encryptData) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPDistributedSecurityTokenCache..ctor(String
>   name, TimeSpan timeToLive, SPDistributedCacheContainerType
>   containerType, Boolean encrptyData, TimeSpan
>   minimumTokenExpirationWindow) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPDistributedSecurityTokenCacheInitializer.Init(Object
>   state)'.

i'm stuck and i need assistance.

However i dont't know if this is related, when i checked the site using the client laptop, there was a certificate issue (it was using a wildcard cert, different from that of the certificate i binded in OWA server and imported and installed in sharepoint servers) this is my first time handling certificates so i am confused where to start with the resolution.

Comment: I think your posted error is not related to OfficeWebApps Server. You have a ULS-Log in OfficeWebApps-Server. Please post the according log here. You can find it in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\OfficeWebApps\Data\Logs\ULS

Comment: @MHeld hello, i dont see any logs in the OWA Server with the specified  correlation id. does that mean that the connection between the owa server and server is already wrong?

Comment: @MHeld found a new error in ULS: SPShareByLinkHandler.Initialize : Not a ShareByLink request - missing access token

Comment: You can get the LogLocation in your OWA-Configuration with "Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm". You will find the parameter "LogLocation". Please provide more than one line of logs, best would be an entire correlation.

Comment: @MHeld, i found a dumb mistake while testing. i was using the system admin account and it turned out that it will not work for OWA, i switched to a user account and tested it, but i now i have errors with the certificate I binding with OWA not being trusted.

Comment: You could post this information as answer and mark it accepted. Maybe it will help others in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a dumb mistake while testing. i was using the system admin account and it turned out that it will not work for OWA.